# Удаление четных элементов в массиве

Tags: c++, массивы

Здравствуйте! Помогите, пожалуйста, написать код программы на удаление всех четных элементов в массиве. Вот сам код программы:

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* Rus(const char* text);

void main()
{
  int a[100];
  int i,n;
  randomize();
  cout << Rus(" Введите n: ");
  cin >> n;
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) a[i]=random(100);
  for (i=0; i<n; i++) cout<<a[i]<<" ";
  getch();
}

char bufRus[256];
char* Rus(const char* text)
{
CharToOem(text,bufRus);
return bufRus
}
```

Comment: Что Вы подразумеваете под **удалением** элемента массива ?

Остаток массива сдвигается влево и размер массива уменьшается на 1 ?

Comment: @Mary-Angel, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Answer (score 4):

Что ты имеешь в виду под понятием "чётные элементы"? Чётный индекс или чётное число? Если первое, то:

```
for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) a[i]=a[i*2+1];
for(int i=0; i<n/2; i++) cout << a[i] << ' ';
```

Если второе, то:

```
int newsize=0;
for(int i=0; i<n; i++) if(a[i]%2!=0) a[newsize++]=a[i];
for(int i=0; i<newsize; i++) cout << a[i] << " ";
```